# How do I remove/hide all the scrollbars from windows in Windows XP?

Tags: windows-xp, scrollbar, user-interface

How can I remove or hide scrollbars from all Windows XP windows? I don't need them, because I can scroll with my mouse.

Answer (score 2):

It may be possible to do this, but Windows sure doesn't make it easy. If you bring up Display Properties (by right-clicking on the desktop and selecting Properties, for example), you can select the Appearance tab. From there click on Advanced, and pick Scrollbars from the upper pull-down menu, which will permit you to set the scrollbar to a minimal size. However, the default size requirement prevents you from removing the scrollbar entirely, this way; you might be able to disable scrollbars by mucking about in the system files by hand, but I wouldn't begin to know how to accomplish this that way, much less actually suggest someone ATTEMPT it.

Comment: It might be possible to look at the registry changes that are made when you change the option, and then lower the number (if it even is one) from there.

Answer (score 0):

This happens to me often when I use my company's desktop software.  What I do to fix it is go to the primary desktop (ie if you're in another interface, minimize it and go to the one that appears when you start up the computer).  Go to properties by right clicking the desktop.  Go to settings and adjust the pixels to slightly smaller than you previously had.  That fixes mine when I have this issue.  Hope it works for you.